# Bash beginner: Error when tries to copy directory itself when making subdirectories

Tags: bash, subdirectory, copying

- I have a directory with 4 directories in it.
- I want to make a 5th directory (cx1_date) and create 4 empty directories with the same names as those of the original directory
- I then want to copy two files from each of the original directories to the new subdirectories with their respective names
- I think I am getting an error because it tries to copy the PWD itself (as this shows up as a result of the find call), so I tried to include an if statement but I think that it doesn't work

  ```
  now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

  PWD="/nmr/charlie"

  mkdir $PWD/cx1_$now

  for name in $(find $PWD -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
  if [[ "$name" = "$PWD" && "$PWD" = "$name" ]];
  then 
      :
  else 
      cd $PWD/cx1_$now
      mkdir $PWD/$name
      cd $PWD/$name 
      cp file1.ext $PWD/cx1_$now/$name
      cp file2.ext $PWD/cx1_$now/$name
  fi 
  done
  ```

First line of the error

mkdir: cannot create directory `/nmr/charlie/cx1_05_15_2012//nmr/charlie/cx1_05_15_2012': No such file or directory

Thanking you in advance for any help you can give!

Charlie

Comment: Include the error in the question

Comment: you can debug your shell script by inserting `set -vx` near the top of the script. (The answers below look to solve the problem). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `mkdir` doesn't want the `$PWD`:

```
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

DIR="/nmr/charlie"

mkdir $DIR/cx1_$now

for name in $(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
    if [[ "$name" != "$DIR" ]]
    then 
        (cd $DIR/cx1_$now; mkdir $name)
        (cd $DIR/$name 
         cp file1.ext $DIR/cx1_$now/$name
         cp file2.ext $DIR/cx1_$now/$name
        )
    fi
done
```

Also, PWD is a built-in variable; you shouldn't set it (except via the `cd` command).

You don't need the symmetric test in the `if`; you can use `!=` instead of `=` to avoid an empty `then` clause (OK, it contains a nice anodyne `:` command; you don't need it if you invert the test).

I usually put `cd` operations into sub-shells; that way, I get less confused.  An alternative for the second `mkdir` line is this, which doesn't need the `cd` or subshell:

```
mkdir -p $DIR/cx1_$now/$name
```

I recommend using the ISO 8601 format for dates, such as:

```
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
```

That way, the directories will sort in date order automatically.

---

> I still get the error:
>
> ```
> mkdir: cannot create directory `/nmr/charlie/directory_name_1': File exists
> /home/charlie/Desktop/scripts/test.sh: line 16: cd: /nmr/charlie//nmr/charlie/directory_name_1: No such file or directory
> ```

The problem likely means we've not filtered correctly yet.  For example, each time you create a back up directory, all the previous backup directories will be backed up into the new one, which a little excessive.  So, the other part of the exercise is filtering the output of `find` better.

...And we should be using the base name of the directory, and we can avoid all `cd` operations too:

```
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

DIR="/nmr/charlie"

mkdir $DIR/cx1_$now

for name in $(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v '/cx1_[^/]*$')
do
    if [[ "$name" != "$DIR" ]]
    then
        targetdir=$DIR/cx1_$now/$(basename $name)
        mkdir -p $targetdir
        cp $name/file1.ext $name/file2.ext $targetdir
    fi
done
```

You do know about using 'sh -x script.sh' or 'bash -x script.sh' to run the script and see what it is doing.  I'm not even sure that we need the `if` condition with the `grep` filtering out anything that looks like a backup directory from the list.

I note that this only works if the directory paths are sane and contain no spaces.  Things go wrong rather rapidly if you use non-portable files names (where portable names use `[-_.A-Za-z0-9]` only).  Newlines and spaces really make a mess.

Note that this would be simpler if you made the backup in directories under `/nmr/backup/charlie` or anywhere other than under `/nmr/charlie` itself.  However, with care, it can be done in situ as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your help, useful tips, but I still get the error:

mkdir: cannot create directory `/nmr/charlie/directory_name_1': File exists
/home/charlie/Desktop/scripts/test.sh: line 16: cd: /nmr/charlie//nmr/charlie/directory_name_1: No such file or directory

Comment: cool so I used the bash -x thing now to see what it is doing, I thought it troubleshooted without actually implementing the script but I just overwrote a lot of my data by using it! Bit of a mistake there on my part. Is there anyway you can do it conservatively so you can see what it is doing without it actually taking all the cp rm actions etc?

Comment: There are a few tricks.  While you're getting syntax correct, `sh -nv script` can help.  The `-n` means 'no execute' and the `-v` means 'verbose'.  Once you're into testing, make sure you test on a copy of your real data until you're sure it is behaving.  This is doubly crucial if your script can do damage (by removing files or irreversibly altering them).  One other thing I do is put `echo` in front of any dangerous commands until I'm happy they're correct; that shows me (more or less) what would be executed without actually executing.  Otherwise, keep good backups!

Answer (score 2):

You are using $PWD as if it meant both "/nmr/charlie" and "/nmr/charlie/cx1_date". It only means the first one.

Also, when you loop through the folders inside your $PWD, it will include cx1_date as well, because you've already created it, so you should check for that.

And I would not recommend using PWD as a variable name because it can be used for other things.

[EDIT] Also, $name gets the full path of the directory, so you need to use basename to get only the name of the directory without the full path. Also, I made a mistake in the if line and it was meant to be != instead of = on the second comparison. Sorry, I didn't have a shell at the time to test. The code below now works, I've tested it.

This should work:

```
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

DIR="/nmr/charlie"

mkdir $DIR/cx1_$now

for name in $(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
    if [[ "$name" != "$DIR" && "$name" != "$DIR/cx1_$now" ]];
    then 
        targetdir=$(basename $name)
        cd $DIR/cx1_$now
        mkdir $DIR/cx1_$now/$targetdir
        cd $DIR/$targetdir
        cp file1.ext $DIR/cx1_$now/$targetdir
        cp file2.ext $DIR/cx1_$now/$targetdir
    fi 
done
```

Comment: I get the following error? I still can't figure out why its doubling it.

/home/charlie/Desktop/scripts/test.sh: line 17: cd: /nmr/charlie//nmr/charlie/cx1_2012_05_15: No such file or directory